# Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

i'm trying to build hadoop from source but when i m trying to build it i get this error
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-main:2.10.0 (/usr/local/hadoop-2.10.0-src/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.5.0 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.5.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:pom:2.5.0 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/2.5.0/maven-bundle-plugin-2.5.0.pom -> [Help 2]